# How can I 'trim' the unnecessary input fields from GenericView?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-generic-views

In my current project i am creating a little CMS so the client will be able to update his gallery on the website with new images and replace the old ones. For this I am using the generic Views to simplify the whole process.

Adding a new image was no problem, but the UpdateView is providing some html elements, which I dont want my client to see:

[image]

Here is the code:

**models.py**

```
class GalleryPicture(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
img = WEBPField(
    verbose_name=_('Image'),
    upload_to=image_folder,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.title}'

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('Galerie Überblick')

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'GalleryPictures'
```

I am also using a custom field for images, so all the uploaded pictures would be automatically converted into WEBP format:

**fields.py**

```
class WEBPFieldFile(ImageFieldFile):

def save(self, name, content, save=True):
    content.file.seek(0)
    image = Image.open(content.file)
    image_bytes = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(fp=image_bytes, format="WEBP")
    image_content_file = ContentFile(content=image_bytes.getvalue())
    super().save(name, image_content_file, save)

class WEBPField(models.ImageField):
attr_class = WEBPFieldFile
```

**urls.py**

```
    path('content-manager/overview/gallery/<int:pk>/edit', EditGalleryImage.as_view(), name="Bild ändern")
```

**views.py**

```
class EditGalleryImage(UpdateView):
  model = GalleryPicture
  template_name = './pages/content_edit/edit_gallery_image.html'
  fields = ['title', 'img',]
```

**edit_gallery_image.html**

```
    <div class="form-content">
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
        
            {{ form }}

            <input class="submit-button link-button" type="submit" value="Speichern" name="save-image">
            <input class="submit-button link-button" type="submit" value="Löschen" name="delete-image">
    </form>
</div>
```

My first approach was to create a custom form model in forms.py and define some classes there for this html elements, so I could hide them with JS:

**forms.py**

```
class UpdateImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = GalleryPicture
    fields = ('title', 'img')
    widgets = {
        'img': forms.ImageField(
            widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'nice'})
        ),
    }
```

But if I will use my **views.py** like this:

```
class EditGalleryImage(UpdateView):
  model = GalleryPicture
  template_name = './pages/content_edit/edit_gallery_image.html'
  form_class = UpdateImageForm
```

I get an Error:

```
AttributeError at /content-manager/overview/gallery/1/edit
'ImageField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'
```

and the fixes, which I have found for this error, were also not helpful in my case.

Maybe one of you knows the better approach for 'trimming' these HTML elements or knows how to solve this error? I would be very grateful for every answer.

Comment: Look at your EditGalleryImage view  and see what fields you're including in that view.

Comment: @fkay There are the 'title' and 'img' included, but with 'img' are also coming these other fields like this checkbox which I would like to exclude. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: you can use Django crispy forms to make it look nicer. They're very easy to setup and make your upload forms look nice.

Comment: there may be a way to modify the Django upload template I would think but you need to check the docs yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use Django crispy forms to make it presentable. I would assume they would also provide you the option for more fine grain control on what is rendered with the form.